# Javascript/Jquery how to get Key from Key/Value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a field called City that is a drop down. It has a key value pair.

To get the value, I can simply do the following in Jquery:

```
    var city = $("#city").val();
```

How do I get the key value though?

Comment: what would be the key in your example?

Comment: Does this mean the `option` elements have a `value` and non-standard `key` attribute? Your question does not contain sufficient information to be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you want the text of the selected option:

```
$('#city').find('option:selected').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

if it's a option within a select, try `.text()`.